# wso2, wsf-php segmentation fault on script shut down

Tags: php, soap, wso2, wsh

I'm trying to use WSO2 Web Services Framework for PHP 2.1.0 on Kubuntu 11.04 with php 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.7

I have minimal php installation, xml, xslt, lib-ssl, libaxis2c libraries:

```
apt-get install php5 php5-dev php5-xsl libxml2-dev libssl-dev libaxis2c
```

Everything went fine -- compiled, and installed, added to include path.
I see the library in php -i output:

```
wsf

wsf support => enabled
wsf version => 2.1.0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
wsf.attachment_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
wsf.enable_attachment_caching => 0 => 0
wsf.home => /usr/lib/php5/20090626/wsf_c => /usr/lib/php5/20090626/wsf_c
wsf.log_level => 4 => 4
wsf.log_path => /tmp => /tmp
wsf.rm_db_dir => /tmp => /tmp
```

So I've tried to access simple web-service:
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl

Like this:

```
$client = new WSClient(array(
   'wsdl'=>'http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl'
));
$proxy = $client->getProxy();

$response = $proxy->CelsiusToFahrenheit(array('Celsius'=>11));
```

Script seems to run fine -- got wsdl, connected, parse response and I can print_r the response data:

```
Array
(
    [CelsiusToFahrenheitResult] => 51.8
)
```

Then script trying to finish and falls with segmentation fault:

```
[Fri Apr  6 15:42:35 2012] [info]  [rampart] rampart_mod shutdown
[Fri Apr  6 15:42:35 2012] [info]  [rahas] Rahas module shutdown
Segmentation fault
```

If I'll comment the soap call, then segmentations fault will disappear.

Is there a way to eliminate this segfault? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of SSL are you using?
I've been trying to figure this out for myself as well and come across this
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/WSFPHP-467

Comment: Sorry for late answer (I was on vacation).  
  
    $ ssh -v
    OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0h 12 Mar 2012

I've dropped the attepts to use this lib, in favour of  
wse-php and manual payload processing (for MTOM)  

Thank you for tip anyway. I'll try to compile just for fun :)